# Only showing a part of a website using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Okay right, I'm using a uiwebview.
But I only want one bit of it to show, so when the uiwebview loads, only a certain bit shows. and the rest of the website doesnt.
how do i do this
thanks

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the content, ideas on top of my head:
Append another CSS file and hide containers you don't want to show with regular CSS selectors.

1. First you have to download the content manually, I prefere
   NSURLConnection.
2. Append the css file
3. Save the file to disk
4. And load the newly created file

Comment: Okay ive just decided to make separate website optimized for iphone, thanks anyway